# Getting a Syntax error when trying to use a method using ArrayLists?

Tags: java, string, for-loop, arraylist, integer

So right now I am getting an Syntax error when I am trying to use a method that does not return any value (is void), and that takes in arguments `ArrayList<E> fileList`. My goal is to take in a text file that has both String, and Integer objects, and in the remove method if it finds a Integer then it will be removed from the list. This is so it will only be leaving the Strings at the end. Here is the code that shows both the reading of the file, and the `removeInts` method I am trying to use:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") //IDE told me to add this for adding objects to the ArrayList
public <E> ArrayList<E> readFile(){
    ArrayList<E> fileList = new ArrayList<E>();
    try {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(file); //would not let me do this without error handling
        while(read.hasNext()){ //while there is still stuff to add it will keep filling up the ArrayList
            fileList.add((E)read.next());
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    removeInts(fileList);
    return fileList;    
}

public void removeInts(ArrayList<E> fileList){
    for(int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++){
        if(fileList.get(i) instanceof Integer){
            fileList.remove(i);
        }
        else{
            //does nothing, does not remove the object if it is a string
        }
    }
```

I am getting the syntax error at `removeInts(fileList)`.

Comment: Please always post the complete error message, word-for-word with your question.

Comment: Note that `read.next()` *always* returns a `String`. There are never going to be any `Integer` objects in that list.

Comment: This code doesn't make much sense. Scanner.next() returns a String, not an E. So the list will never contain any Integer, and the method should return a List<String>. You shouldn't ignore the compiler warnings. They tell you that your code is wrong.

Comment: Is there a way then to tell if it is an Integer, I am stuck on how to properly get that to work.

Comment: It is NEVER an Integer. next() returns a String. I have no idea of what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: If you mean detecting strings like `"12345"`, then you can parse the string using `Integer.parseInt`. But in any case you shouldn't add it to the list at all if the parse succeeds, which would allow you to declare it as `List<String>`. In short, read about [Integer.parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29), pay attention to the exception it throws, and re-design your program. It shouldn't be generic at all.

Comment: I am trying to be able to remove ints from a text file, only leaving strings left. Say for example I had a text file that said "A B C 1 2 3", first the scanner (I need to use a scanner) would take in the file, and put it into an ArrayList. Then when I use the remove method it would take out all values that are Integers, and leave alone the Strings. The final output at the end would be "A B C".

Comment: (a) In a file that contains `A B C 1 2 3` **all six elements are strings**. But some of them (`1`,`2`,`3`) can be *converted* (parsed) into integers while others (`A`,`B`,`C`) can't. But when you read them they are all strings. (b) You shouldn't put mixed types into a list. Instead, simply **don't add the items that are bad to the list in the first place**.

Comment: That is what I am trying to do, I am just not sure how.

Comment: Following advice by @RealSkeptic, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the signature of removeInts to be generic:

```
public <E> void removeInts(ArrayList<E> fileList)
```

Comment: Wow that was simple. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am happy to help! Please accept the answer if it solved it

Answer (score 3):

As others pointed out, your list will never contain an `Integer`, because `next()` returns a `String`.

Given your last comment:

> I am trying to be able to remove ints from a text file, only leaving strings left. Say for example I had a text file that said `"A B C 1 2 3"`, first the `Scanner` (I need to use a scanner) would take in the file, and put it into an `ArrayList`. Then when I use the `remove` method it would take out all values that are Integers, and leave alone the Strings. The final output at the end would be `"A B C"`.

Don't first load them as Integer and then remove them. Instead, don't load them:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner("A B C 1 2 3")) {
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        if (sc.hasNextInt())
            sc.nextInt(); // get and discard
        else
            list.add(sc.next());
    }
}
System.out.println(list);
```

*Output*

```
[A, B, C]
```

Comment: Is there a reason it is outputting this first, and then what is in the text file?       [{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1348\cocoasubrtf170, {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0, Helvetica;}, {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}, \margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0, \pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural, \f0\fs24, \cf0,

Comment: @FyreeW Your file was saved as an [RTF file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format). Save it as a plain text file.

Comment: Changed it to a .txt file,worked after that. Thank you @Andreas for pointing that out.